# printing/log c++ stings indented w.r.t. depth of function call

Tags: c++, logging

I want to print some strings in functions, but indented depending on how far the depth of the function calls has gone. My solution so far includes a class from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649035/c-calculate-depth-of-the-function-calls-that-led-to-the-current-function/69649401#69649401) like the following:

```
class DepthCounter
{
    static int depth;

public:
    DepthCounter(const std::string& name)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(depth*2, ' ') << name << "  // depth " << depth << '\n';
        ++depth;
    }

    ~DepthCounter()
    {
        --depth;
    }
};

int DepthCounter::depth = 0;

void func1(){
    DepthCounter dc("name1");
}

void func2(){
    DepthCounter dc("name2");
    func1();
}
```

so the print in the first construction will have 1 depth and the second one 2 depth (indent).
but I want to make this print multiple times. that is

```
void func2(){
    DepthCounter dc("name0");
    DepthCounter dc1("name1");
    DepthCounter dc2("name2");
    DepthCounter dc3("name3");
    func1();
}
```

but I don't find it nice, let alone the fact that this construction increases the depth although it is still in the same function. Is there a better way do have such functionality?

ideally I want something like:

```
void func1(){
    funcX("name5");
}

void func2(){
    funcX("name0");
    funcX("name1");
    funcX("name2");
    funcX("name3");
    func1();
}
```

Does anyone know an alternative way?

Comment: If you want multiple depth counters, you could make it a template with an `int` parameter. This would allow to manage multiple of such counters concurrently without the necessity to change your concept much.

Comment: Maybe, you're looking for a kind of stack trace (aka. call stack) like you may have seen already in gdb. I roughly remember that there already was once such a question. The stack trace part of gdb is provided by a library which could be used in your application as well. Nevertheless, it will be a platform-dependent solution always probably, as such details are usually subject of implementation detail rather than the C++ standard.

Comment: FYI: [SO: print call stack in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899870/7478597) (found by [google "site:stackoverflow.com c++ using stack trace in application"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%2B%2B+using+stack+trace+in+application))

Comment: Alipapa: Did the answer help? Please ask if it was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the function name inside the `DepthCounter` and provide an `operator<<` overload to use inside the functions:

```
class DepthCounter {
    static int depth;
    std::string m_name;
public:
    DepthCounter(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) {
        std::cout << std::string(depth*2, ' ') << "->" << m_name << '\n';
        ++depth;
    }
    ~DepthCounter() {
        --depth;
        std::cout << std::string(depth*2, ' ') << "<-" << m_name << '\n';
    }

    template<class T>
    friend DepthCounter& operator<<(DepthCounter& dc, const T& val) {
        std::cout << std::string(depth*2, ' ') << dc.m_name << ": " << val << '\n';
        return dc;
    }
};

int DepthCounter::depth = 0;
```

And use it like so:

```
void func1(){
    DepthCounter dc(__func__);
    dc << "here's something";
}

void func2(){
    DepthCounter dc(__func__);
    dc << "name1";
    dc << "name2";
    func1();
    dc << "some more after calling func1";
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/81M5jP4rq)